# Putting values of a dictionary in a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I want make a graph of a part of the values of a dictionary.

I already stored the necessary values in a variable, but I just don't understand how to put them in a simple graph with just the numbers 1 to 500 on the x-axis and my values on the y-axis.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Plot frequencies of the most 500 words
frequencies = freqs_sorted[len(freqs_sorted)-500:len(freqs_sorted)]
```

Everything I tried so far resulted in an empty graph. Thanks in advance!

Comment: But *what* have you tried? There's no graphing code here.

Comment: I see no dictionary in the code you have posted.  Why are you talking about _"…the values of a dictionary…"_ ?

Comment: A more idiomatic way of finding the last 500 items in a list is `last500 = mylist[-500:]`

Answer (score 0):

From the matplotlib [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.plot(range(1, 501), frequencies)
plt.show()
```

P.S. In matplotlib you often have several ways to draw whatever you want. It is just one of them. Here is shorter version from @gboffi:

```
plt.plot(frequencies)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you use the (`plt`) stateful interface you can omit the `fig=...`, `ax=...` stuff.  Moreover, you don't need a `range` to plot the frequencies, just a `plt.plot(frequencies)` will do as well.

Comment: @NoorvandenBerg If you are satisfied with this answer, you should _accept_ it.

Comment: @gboffi: Not if you want the first data point correspond to x = 1 as achieved by `range(1, 501)` ;)

Comment: @Sheldore right, but in both cases the x-axis runs from 0 to 500 and I guess you need a good magnifying glass to see the difference... ;;-)